# Oracle Database 11g .pkb and .pks files

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have filename.pkb and filename.pks files. Those files have stored procedures inside, how can I load them in to schema if .pks file contains stored procedure signatures and .pkb file contains binary source.

Comment: you mean the pkb files are wrapped?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you telling about, file source is like this
_§~‰í}©¢— š–&ëŠ–§¢ÇµÛ^yÛm¸ßn¢{_iÇŸ¢{_jh¥É6¡¢f©jz,{]µ×®7çŽ6ãô­ÊWƒyø§ŠØ¨žÏé2Ê
¢¹š–XŒ²ƒh®f¥v+Ì²ƒh®f¥™ªàŠ}šf«‚)_

Comment: Where did the files come from? Is the `.pkb` compressed and it's lost its extension (`.gz`, `.zip`, whatever)?

Comment: Those files come from customer, and i need to use stored procedures from those files, nope i received it in .pkb format already.

Comment: Well it doesn't appear to be in normal `.pkb` format since that is text not binary, even if it's wrapped, so something else is going on. Have you asked the customer how they produced the files, and if they compressed or encrypted them in any way?

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected to the database with a user that has the correct rights using sqlplus you should be able to do the following:

```
@filename.pks
@filename.pkb
```

Should load the specification and body.

Bobby

Answer (score 0):

Just compile them both. If the pkb files appear to contain binary, it's likely just been [obfuscated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/wrap.htm) and will compile anyway.

Comment: How can I compile both of them? It's creating package successfully when I'm trying to run .pks via sqlplus, and creating package with stored procedure signature, but when I'm trying to load .pkb file it gives me errors like _SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ŚYZH]X..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ŚYZH]X..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "NĆBB..." - rest of line ignored._

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of .plb files. Will it compile with if you rename it to a .plb extension?